# Sorting data in a list using .sort()

Tags: python, sorting

I have a list of numbers that I need to sort to get different calculations done and I noticed that the .sort() function is sorting 2 digit numbers (10-99) and 3 digit numbers (100-999) separately in the list so I end up getting the wrong values for min(), max() and the median, any idea why this is happening?

before sorting:

```
[' 75.0', ' 82.43', ' 112.11', ' 89.93', ' 103.19', ' 80.6', ' 113.44', ' 105.44', ' 95.54', ' 121.98', ' 114.25', ' 109.84', ' 90.48', ' 105.84', ' 82.89', ' 113.64', ' 102.73', ' 104.57', ' 100.83', ' 75.59', ' 79.86', ' 91.11', ' 94.75', ' 109.89', ' 117.39', ' 74.71', ' 71.04', ' 92.97', ' 88.87', ' 92.95', ' 86.67', ' 101.46', ' 92.4', ' 85.2', ' 107.19', ' 117.81', ' 90.95', ' 82.02', ' 87.31', ' 106.53', ' 86.28', ' 106.62', ' 107.57', ' 89.38', ' 105.88', ' 74.45', ' 90.03', ' 107.96', ' 77.42', ' 98.9', ' 109.81', ' 102.51', ' 116.71', ' 82.92', ' 81.78', ' 74.42', ' 76.27', ' 73.84', ' 75.55', ' 102.29', ' 108.1', ' 98.84', ' 101.48', ' 77.75', ' 98.57', ' 70.31', ' 78.28', ' 80.18']
```

and after sorting

```
[' 100.83', ' 101.46', ' 101.48', ' 102.29', ' 102.51', ' 102.73', ' 103.19', ' 104.57', ' 105.44', ' 105.84', ' 105.88', ' 106.53', ' 106.62', ' 107.19', ' 107.57', ' 107.96', ' 108.1', ' 109.81', ' 109.84', ' 109.89', ' 112.11', ' 113.44', ' 113.64', ' 114.25', ' 116.71', ' 117.39', ' 117.81', ' 121.98', ' 70.31', ' 71.04', ' 73.84', ' 74.42', ' 74.45', ' 74.71', ' 75.0', ' 75.55', ' 75.59', ' 76.27', ' 77.42', ' 77.75', ' 78.28', ' 79.86', ' 80.18', ' 80.6', ' 81.78', ' 82.02', ' 82.43', ' 82.89', ' 82.92', ' 85.2', ' 86.28', ' 86.67', ' 87.31', ' 88.87', ' 89.38', ' 89.93', ' 90.03', ' 90.48', ' 90.95', ' 91.11', ' 92.4', ' 92.95', ' 92.97', ' 94.75', ' 95.54', ' 98.57', ' 98.84', ' 98.9']
```

Comment: You have a list of strings, not floats.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because you have a list of strings , so it is getting sorted in lexicographical order , If you are sure the list only have float values (in strings) , the use the keys argument to convert those strings to float while sorting. Example -

```
l.sort(float)
```

If you want to convert the complete list to float (since you say you want to take mean / median , etc later ) , then use -

```
l = list(map(float, l))
```

For Python 2.x , the list(..) is not needed as map() returns a list .

And if you are converting the complete list to float , then you do not need the above sort() method with keys argument , normal .sort() should work.

Comment: oh ok thanks! still new to python and I assumed it works the same since I had no issues with other lists containing smaller numbers

Comment: Ok, but wouldn't it be better to just convert the list to floats in the first place? If OP leaves them as strings, it's just going to make it harder to find min and max and median.

Comment: Good idea , I have added code for that as well . Thanks :-)

Comment: yeah I've tried converting the whole list now since I'm not that familiar with using lambda and it worked just fine

Comment: I would say `float` instead of `lambda x: float(x)`

Comment: Yea , float would be better . Thanks , updated that in the answer.

Comment: @kattoch: `lambda` is just a convenient way of creating simple "throwaway" functions. But as saulspatz just mentioned, there's an even easier way to do it here. When you call `.sort()` with a key function then it uses that function to create an invisible list that it uses for the sorting, and then that list is thrown away. A similar thing happens if you pass a  key function to `min()` or `max()`. So if you need to do several arithmetic things with a list of number strings it's much more efficient to just build a list of numbers yourself from the strings & work with that.

Comment: yeah I ended up just creating a new list and appended the float values to it since I'll be using the data more than once anyways, thanx for the explanation